# Marionette.js: CompositeView: getItemView always returns 'undefined' on initialize

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a compositeView and ItemViews as follows (simplified version of my views):

```
testView1 = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#test-view-1'
}
testView2 = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#test-view-2'
}

TestView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: '#test-template',
    itemViewContainer:'tbody',
    itemView: testView1,
    getItemView: function(item){
        console.log('item');        //<==== FIRED 101 TIMES
        if (!item) {                //<==== WHY DO I NEED THIS
            return testView1;       //<==== WHY DO I NEED THIS
        } else {
            return ('testView' + item.id);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, when the CompositeView initializes, it runs the `getItemView` code BEFORE it passes an `item` into it, producing an error. Without the `if` conditional that I have added in, the view breaks.

My collection that is passed into the composite view contains 100 models, and the `console.log('item');` gets fired 101 times, the first time is always 'undefined', and the remaining 100 times are the 100 models as expected.

My question is, why do I need to check if the `item` exists every time and is there something I can do to avoid needing this check?

Comment: It's just a guessing, but maybe you are passing to the composite view costructor a collection before it has been completely fetched from the server?

Comment: @Ingro, The CollectionView is being created from the `success: function()` of my collection fetch. The collection is complete at the time the issue arises. I am expecting 100 models in my collection and that is what I am getting, but `getItemView` is fired 101 times. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried in my code with your custom getItemView function and I get the same behaviour.

Tracing the call it seems that getItemView is getting called once in the CompositeView's constructor to assign the itemView you passed to the CompositeView's object: `this.itemView = this.getItemView();`

So I think you are doing it right by checking if a item is passed before returning the correct itemView instance.

Comment: I agree that doing the `if` conditional is the correct action, and it is functioning fine while having this check. To me, however, I cannot see the need to call `getItemView` until the CompositeView begins the iteration of the models passed in. It seems like a flaw in the Marionette library. I will keep my check in place, however 'hacky' it seems to be. Thank you for taking the time to look into the issue. @Ingro